# Device Tree bindings for additional pin in i2c node

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, device-tree

I am trying to add a reset pin to a i2c device that I have been working with. It seems that the results from the get of the property are returning null.  Is it possible to get a handled for a GPIO in this manner?

The device tree definition looks like THI

```
&PICO_DWARF_I2C1 {
    status = "okay";

    goodix: gt811@38 {
        compatible = "goodix,gt811";

        interrupts = <GPIO_NO(PICO_EXT_GPIO_P44) 2>;

        reset-gpios = <GPIO_NO(PICO_EXT_GPIO_P32) GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>; 

        touchscreen-size-x = <1024>;
        touchscreen-size-y = <600>;
    };




};
```

The source looks like this. Other components that work but are omitted like the reg info and all that. It's the pins that I am struggling with.

```
static int goodix_get_gpio_config(struct goodix_ts_data *ts)
{
    int error;
    struct device *dev;
    struct gpio_desc *gpiod;

    if (!ts->client)
        return -EINVAL;
    dev = &ts->client->dev;
    struct device_node *np = &dev->of_node;


    /* Get the interrupt GPIO pin number */
    gpiod = of_get_property(dev->of_node, "interrupts", NULL);
    if (IS_ERR(gpiod)) {
        error = PTR_ERR(gpiod);
        if (error != -EPROBE_DEFER)
            dev_dbg(dev, "Failed to get %s GPIO: %d\n",
                GOODIX_GPIO_INT_NAME, error);
        return error;
    }

    ts->int_pin = gpiod;

    /* Get the reset line GPIO pin number */
    gpiod = of_get_property(dev->of_node, "reset-gpios", NULL);
    if (IS_ERR(gpiod)) {
        error = PTR_ERR(gpiod);
        if (error != -EPROBE_DEFER)
            dev_dbg(dev, "Failed to get %s GPIO: %d\n",
                GOODIX_GPIO_RST_NAME, error);
        return error;
    }

    ts->reset_pin = gpiod;
return 0;
}
```

Is this the correct approach or should I be calling a different function?

Comment: That's a reference to a definition. It's correct.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the GPIO_NO() function was unnecessary in the reset-gpios property. Once it was removed the property loaded.